# Find start and stop in a time series

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I would like to understand if there is a way to find, using a linq exp, all start and stop windows (delimited by a start and end values) of a given time series.
I know that this can be achieved via a normal loop but I like expanding my knowledge if possible.

Data is stored in a ordered list of "TagData" (`List<TagData>`)

```
class TagData
{
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public string Tag { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

The easy way it is when the contents of the data are perfectly alternated such as:

```
timestamp               | tag       | value
2018-12-01 00:10:00.000 | extrg_01  | 1
2018-12-01 00:15:02.000 | extrg_01  | 0
2018-12-01 00:25:50.000 | extrg_01  | 1
2018-12-01 00:45:11.000 | extrg_01  | 0
```

At this point given the initial value = 1 and end value = 0, the result will be something along these lines:

```
timestamp_start         |timestamp_end              | tag       | nrOfSeconds
2018-12-01 00:10:00.000 |2018-12-01 00:15:02.000    | extrg_01  | 302
2018-12-01 00:25:50.000 |2018-12-01 00:45:01.000    | extrg_01  | 1161
```

But there also could be some "dirty" data that doesn't need to be accounted for:

```
timestamp               | tag       | value
2018-12-01 00:10:00.000 | extrg_01  | 1
2018-12-01 00:12:02.000 | extrg_01  | 1
2018-12-01 00:15:02.000 | extrg_01  | 0
2018-12-01 00:16:01.000 | extrg_01  | 0
2018-12-01 00:25:50.000 | extrg_01  | 1
2018-12-01 00:45:11.000 | extrg_01  | 0
```

In this case the end result should not differ from the first example because all values after the defined initial value (in this case was = 1) are not to be considered and likewise, only the first end value (in this case was = 0) will be considered for the calculation.

I forgot to add the linq expression I'm trying to edit in order to achieve the result:
Unfortunately I cannot understand how to add where conditions within this .Zip (if it is possible at all) to look for a specific value and respect a time condition to always find the next available value.

```
var diffs = tagDataList.Skip(1)
            .Zip(tagDataList,
                (curr, prev) => new
                {
                    CurrTag = curr.Tag,
                    CurrValue = curr.Value,
                    CurrDate = curr.Timestamp,
                    PrevDate = prev.Timestamp,
                    DiffToPrev = Math.Abs((curr.Timestamp - prev.Timestamp).TotalSeconds)
                })
            .ToList();
```

Comment: The best way is to create an IEnunerate method which gets start/stop times from the list.  The you can use Next.  Try : class TagData : IEnumerator

Comment: You could try using the Aggregate method, but I am not sure this would be particularly readable compared to writing out a normal loop.

Comment: Would you provide the normal loop that you are going to convert to LINQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably many ways of doing this. I will give it a shot:

I assume that you want different tags to be handled separately. This is my approach:

1. Group the entries by tag.
2. For each group:

   1. Remove all entries with value 0 from the beginning of the list.
   2. If there are two or more adjacent entries with the same value, only keep the first one.

      - Now we have a list starting with a value of 1 and alternating between 1s and 0s.
   3. Zip the 1s together with the 0s to compute the timespans.
3. Finally flatten all the results from each group

I used this test data:

```
var list = new List<TagData> {
    new TagData { Timestamp = DateTime.Parse("2018-12-01 00:09:00.000"), Tag = "extrg_01", Value = 0 },
    new TagData { Timestamp = DateTime.Parse("2018-12-01 00:10:00.000"), Tag = "extrg_01", Value = 1 },
    new TagData { Timestamp = DateTime.Parse("2018-12-01 00:10:00.000"), Tag = "extrg_02", Value = 1 },
    new TagData { Timestamp = DateTime.Parse("2018-12-01 00:12:02.000"), Tag = "extrg_01", Value = 1 },
    new TagData { Timestamp = DateTime.Parse("2018-12-01 00:15:02.000"), Tag = "extrg_01", Value = 0 },
    new TagData { Timestamp = DateTime.Parse("2018-12-01 00:16:01.000"), Tag = "extrg_01", Value = 0 },
    new TagData { Timestamp = DateTime.Parse("2018-12-01 00:15:02.000"), Tag = "extrg_02", Value = 0 },
    new TagData { Timestamp = DateTime.Parse("2018-12-01 00:25:50.000"), Tag = "extrg_01", Value = 1 },
    new TagData { Timestamp = DateTime.Parse("2018-12-01 00:45:11.000"), Tag = "extrg_01", Value = 0 },
    new TagData { Timestamp = DateTime.Parse("2018-12-01 00:25:50.000"), Tag = "extrg_02", Value = 1 },
    new TagData { Timestamp = DateTime.Parse("2018-12-01 00:45:11.000"), Tag = "extrg_02", Value = 0 },
};
```

Class definitions:

```
class TagData
{
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public string Tag { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
}

class TagSummary
{
    public DateTime TimestampStart { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimestampEnd { get; set; }
    public string Tag { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan TimeSpan => TimestampEnd - TimestampStart;
}
```

Code:

```
var summaries =
    list.GroupBy(tagdata => tagdata.Tag) // Step (1)
    .Select(group => // Step (2)
    {
        var data = group
            .SkipWhile(tagdata => tagdata.Value == 0) // Step (2.1)
            .Aggregate(new List<TagData>(), (acc, tagdata) => // Step (2.2)
            {
              if (acc.LastOrDefault()?.Value != tagdata.Value)
                  acc.Add(tagdata);
              return acc;
            });

        var ones = data.Where(datatag => datatag.Value == 1);
        var zeros = data.Where(datatag => datatag.Value == 0);
        var result = ones.Zip(zeros, (startTag, endTag) => { // Step (2.3)
            return new TagSummary { TimestampStart = startTag.Timestamp, TimestampEnd = endTag.Timestamp, Tag = startTag.Tag };
        });

        return result;
    })
    .SelectMany(x => x); // Step (3)

Console.WriteLine("timestamp_start     | timestamp_end       | tag      | nrOfSeconds");
foreach (var summary in summaries)
    Console.WriteLine($"{summary.TimestampStart:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} | {summary.TimestampEnd:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} | {summary.Tag,-8} | {summary.TimeSpan.TotalSeconds:0}");
```

The output is as you've specified:

```
timestamp_start     | timestamp_end       | tag      | nrOfSeconds
2018-12-01 00:10:00 | 2018-12-01 00:15:02 | extrg_01 | 302
2018-12-01 00:25:50 | 2018-12-01 00:45:11 | extrg_01 | 1161
2018-12-01 00:10:00 | 2018-12-01 00:15:02 | extrg_02 | 302
2018-12-01 00:25:50 | 2018-12-01 00:45:11 | extrg_02 | 1161
```

Comment: yes the tags had to be managed separately, and it uses linq expressions as I asked for. I already had a solution implemented with normal loops.

Answer (score 0):

I did it as an IEnumerator so I could use foreach.  I added a property so the code returns both start and end time.

```
sing System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;

namespace ConsoleApplication94
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<TagData> list = new List<TagData>() {
                new TagData() { Timestamp = DateTime.Parse("2018-12-01 00:10:00.000"), Tag = "extrg_01", Value = 1},
                new TagData() { Timestamp = DateTime.Parse("2018-12-01 00:12:02.000"), Tag = "extrg_01", Value = 1},
                new TagData() { Timestamp = DateTime.Parse("2018-12-01 00:15:02.000"), Tag = "extrg_01", Value = 0},
                new TagData() { Timestamp = DateTime.Parse("2018-12-01 00:16:01.000"), Tag = "extrg_01", Value = 0},
                new TagData() { Timestamp = DateTime.Parse("2018-12-01 00:25:50.000"), Tag = "extrg_01", Value = 1},
                new TagData() { Timestamp = DateTime.Parse("2018-12-01 00:45:11.000"), Tag = "extrg_01", Value = 0}
            };

            TagData data = new TagData(list);

            foreach(TagData tagData in data)
            {
                DateTime start = tagData.Timestamp;
                DateTime end = tagData.Endstamp;
                double seconds = tagData.numberOfSeconds;
            }

        }
    }
    class TagData : IEnumerator<TagData>
    {
        public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
        public string Tag { get; set; }
        public double Value { get; set; }
        public DateTime Endstamp { get; set; }
        public double numberOfSeconds;

        private List<TagData> listData;
        private int curIndex;
        private int endIndex;
        private TagData curTagData;

        public TagData() { }
        public TagData(List<TagData> collection)
        {
            listData = collection;
            curIndex = -1;
            endIndex = -1;
            curTagData = default(TagData);

        }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            if (curIndex != -1) curIndex = endIndex;
            while ((++curIndex < listData.Count()) && (listData[curIndex].Value != 1)) { }
            if (curIndex < listData.Count())
            {
                endIndex = curIndex;
                while ((endIndex < listData.Count()) && (listData[endIndex].Value != 0)) endIndex++;
                if (endIndex >= listData.Count()) return false;
                listData[curIndex].Endstamp = listData[endIndex].Timestamp;
                listData[curIndex].numberOfSeconds = (listData[curIndex].Endstamp - listData[curIndex].Timestamp).TotalSeconds;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
            curTagData = listData[curIndex];
            return true;
        }

        public void Reset() { curIndex = -1; endIndex = -1; }

        void IDisposable.Dispose() { }

        public TagData Current
        {
            get { return curTagData; }
        }


        object IEnumerator.Current
        {
            get { return Current; }
        }

        public TagData  GetEnumerator()
        {
            return new TagData(listData);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on *AndersCarstensen*'s classes and seed data:

```
var z = list
        .Where((t, index) => t.Value == 1 && list[index - 1].Value != 1)
        .Select(t =>
            new TagSummary
            {
                TimestampStart = t.Timestamp,
                TimestampEnd = list.First(x => x.Timestamp > t.Timestamp && x.Value == 0).Timestamp,
                Tag = t.Tag
            }
        );
/*
OUTPUT:
Start: 01.12.2018 0:10:00, End: 01.12.2018 0:15:02, Diff: 00:05:02, Tag: extrg_01
Start: 01.12.2018 0:25:50, End: 01.12.2018 0:45:11, Diff: 00:19:21, Tag: extrg_01
Start: 01.12.2018 0:25:50, End: 01.12.2018 0:45:11, Diff: 00:19:21, Tag: extrg_02
*/
```

Comment: When "index" is 0 and goes to -1 throws an "index not in the interval".
Possible solution:
`.Where((t, index) => (index > 1 ? t.Value == 1 && listOfExlusionTriggers[index - 1].Value != 1 : t.Value == 1))`